# Are there any private space probes presently active?

Tags: probe, commercial

Are there any private space probes presently active? 
I'm asking about instruments which have left / are leaving the Earth-Moon system.

I know there is a plan for a telescope in one of the Earth - Sun Lagrange points, but I believe it's a government project.

Comment: No, there are none.

Comment: What motivation would there be for a privately owned company to invest so much money into a space probe?

Comment: Prospecting and selling the data.

Answer (score 3):

The only project I'm aware of is the [Amsat P5a Mars](http://www.amsat-dl.org/p5a/p5a-to-mars.pdf) (PDF) project for an amateur radio relay satellite, but that's still in the [planning stage](http://www.ticket-to-mars.org/en_EN/mission.html).

Answer (score 3):

Planetary Resources hopes to launch [Arkyd prospector probes](http://www.planetaryresources.com/technology/). The Arkyd 100 and 200 would be in the earth-moon neighborhood. But the Arkyd 300 would leave the earth-moon neighborhood and orbit an asteroid on a heliocentric orbit.