# What's next for Planetary Resources?

Tags: artificial-satellite, asteroid, planetary-resources

The company Planetary Resources had great success with their Arkyd-6 mission earlier this year and were recently purchased by a ConsenSys. I'm wondering if they have published any plans about future missions or what's next for the company as [their timeline seems to have no data about the future.](https://www.planetaryresources.com/company/timeline/)

Comment: slightly related: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/4480/12102

Answer (score 1):

Their timeline has no info because Planetary resources is dead. They were unable to meet investor performance goals and then died. The buyout you mentioned was just a talent acquisition move, not a technology acquisition. https://www.geekwire.com/2018/amid-departures-planetary-resources-holds-hope-asteroid-mining-comeback/

Comment: The link does not confirm your assertion that the company is dead. It may be, but I can't tell it from that link.

Comment: Fair point, I suppose this article isn't terribly desriptive. ConsenSys is a blockchain company. They don't even do any sattelites. Also litterally every engineering lead left after the buyout. Someone I know who had connections there is where I got the information to read between the lines.